# Download image from URI android with cache

Tags: android, caching, download

I'm trying to download an image from a uri obtained with FirebaseUi so i can set this image to the headerView in my Navigation Drawer Layout.

I want to have a cache so it only has to be downloaded once the photo and then just use the cache photo.

```
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        View hview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        String personName = auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
        String personEmail = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        String personId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        Uri personPhoto = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();


        if (personPhoto != null){
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) hview.findViewById(R.id.header_imageView);
            // Download photo and set to image
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what's the question? Is there something that's not working as expected?

Comment: I recommend to use UniversalImageLoader

Comment: @m02ph3u5 the question is how can i download the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Picasso library which automatically caches images.

First add the library to your app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Then use it to download and display the image:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    View hview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    String personName = auth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
    String personEmail = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    String personId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Uri personPhoto = auth.getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl();


    if (personPhoto != null) {
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) hview.findViewById(R.id.header_imageView);
        // Download photo and set to image
        Context context = imgView.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context).load(personPhoto).into(imgView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load and cache image.

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150")
.placeholder(R.drawable.image_name_default)
.error(R.drawable.image_name_error)
.into(imageView);
```

This is the sample to load image as well as pass placeholder which will be loaded before image gets downloaded and an error image if the download fails.

> There are many other configurations allowed such as **Memory cache size,
>   Disk cache size, resize, retry using http interceptor and best one is debug enabled which shows if image loaded from cache or from network (setIndicatorsEnabled(true)) .**

Answer (score 0):

Try creating bitmap object from uri and caching the bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), personPhoto);
```

To cache bitmap read this article [Caching Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Better to use picasso library for image downloading and caching.

https://github.com/square/picasso

For downloading and caching you just need to code a single line -

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageURL).placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder).into(imageView);
```

Hope it will work :)